# Restoring C drive image from DVD after booting the computer from bootable disc

Tags: installation, operating-system, boot, diskimage, systemmanagement

If I take **image of C drive** and **burn it on DVD**, can I **restore this image after booting the computer** from a bootable disk? If yes, then how?

I am supposing that restoring C drive image in this way will bring my computer to the exact state of the time when I took image of C drive. Is It correct?

Thanks in advance.

Picarodevosio

Comment: How are you saving the image of drive C? Whatever program you're using to do that should provide functionality to *restore* that image onto another drive/partition.

Comment: I am thinking about using any iso image creator software for taking c drive image but do not know how i can restore it after booting the computer from disc.

Answer (score 1):

The question is kinda stupid, my apologies because as mentioned by Cody Gray, Whatever program you use for taking image of C drive must have a restore option. One such program, which i personally use is "DriveImage XML", available free at http://www.runtime.org/

What you do is you take an image of your C drive or whatever drive you wanna backup (preferably at a time when you believe your system is working absolutely fine). You should create the backup in some external drive. In case your windows later gets corrupted, all you have to do is format C and install a fresh copy of window. Install the above-mentioned or whatever program you used for taking image. select "Restore" and you PC should work as it worked at the time you took the image. 
Hope it works for all